# How to get product details of Merchants Amazon MWS API

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I would like to list some products details of a merchant in Amazon Marketplace using MWS API calls. I used to call `GetLowestOfferListingForSKUSample` API and I got some Lowest prices of each product.

I would like to get `Seller's Name` along with each price. Also `Quantity` left for each seller, `BuyBox %`, `Sessions`, `Rank`, `Inbound`, and `Reserved` for all products of a merchant. Right now I am using `_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_` report to get all SKUs of a Merchant.

Answer (score 2):

A `_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_` report will only include your *own* data, not that of any competitor. There is no API call that does what you want, and to be honest, that's probably the best Amazon can do. Would you want your competitor to know how much you've got on stock?